# propagation model using neural network (I am beginner)

Tags: python, networking, perceptron, propagation

Propagation model:

**P = 10 * n * log10 (d/do)**

*P = path loss (dB)*

*n = the path loss distance exponent*

*d = distance (m)*

*do = reference distance (m)*

The initial idea is to make the loss measurements 'P' with respect to a distance 'd', and to determine the value of 'n'

my question: is this implementation possible using multi-layer Perceptron?

But what could be my inputs and outputs? I thought of something like:
input: distance 'd'
output: Loss "P"

But I could not think of a solution to determine 'n' from these parameters

the idea is that it is something simple, only for study and later improved

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a data for the response (PL) and data for the independent variables in order to find n.
you can find n using that data in SPSS, excel, Matlab etc.

Good luck.